# Update an existing JSON Value inside JSON array

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

```
DECLARE @jsontable TABLE (JsonData nvarchar(max) NULL)

DECLARE @JsonData NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
{
  "Sections": {
    "SectionType": false,
    "SectionName": "Section1"
  },
  "MultiOptions": [
    {
      "Customers": {
        "CustomerName": "name1",
        "Address": "",
        "Source1" : "1"
      },
      "Orders": {
        "OrderName": "item1",
        "Qty": 1,
        "Dest1" : "0",
        "PurchasedQty" : "0"
      },
      "IsMainOption": true
    },
    {
      "Customers": {
        "CustomerName": "name2",
        "Address": "",
        "Source1" : "2"
      },
      "Orders": {
        "OrderName": "item2",
        "Qty": 2,
        "Dest1" : "0",
        "PurchasedQty" : "0"
      },
      "IsMainOption": false
    },
    {
      "Customers": {
        "CustomerName": "name3",
        "Address": "",
        "Source1" : "3"
      },
      "Orders": {
        "OrderName": "item2",
        "Qty": 3,
        "Dest1" : "0",
        "PurchasedQty" : "0"
      },
      "IsMainOption": false
    }
  ],
  "DateUpdated": "2022-05-24",
  "WhoUpdated": 1
}'

INSERT INTO @jsontable
    SELECT @JsonData

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        MultiOptions.[key] AS MultiOptionsKey,
        MultiOptionsCustomers.[key] AS MultiOptionsCustomersKey,
        MultiOptionsCustomers.[value] AS MultiOptionsCustomersValue,
        MultiOptionsOrders.[key] AS MultiOptionsOrdersKey,
        MultiOptionsOrders.[value] AS MultiOptionsOrdersValue,
        JsonData 
    FROM
        @jsontable a 
    CROSS APPLY 
        OPENJSON(JsonData, '$.MultiOptions') MultiOptions
    CROSS APPLY 
        OPENJSON(MultiOptions.value, '$.Customers') MultiOptionsCustomers
    CROSS APPLY 
        OPENJSON(MultiOptions.value, '$.Orders' ) AS MultiOptionsOrders 
)
UPDATE cte 
SET JsonData = JSON_MODIFY(JsonData, '$.MultiOptions[' + MultiOptionsKey + '].Customers[' + MultiOptionsCustomersKey + '].Orders[' + MultiOptionsOrdersKey + '].PurchasedQty', 'Qty#Value')
--select * from cte;
```

I'm getting this error:

> The argument 2 of the "JSON_MODIFY" must be a string literal.

when I execute this query.

I need to update below for all items inside array:

```
UPDATE [MultiOptions.Orders.Dest1] = [MultiOptions.Customers.Source1]
UPDATE [MultiOptions.Customers.PurchasedQty] = [MultiOptions.Customers.Qty]
```

Comment: You need SQL Server 2017 to use a variable as path value.

Comment: How is `'$.MultiOptions[' + MultiOptionsKey + '].Customers[' + MultiOptionsCustomersKey + '].Orders[' + MultiOptionsOrdersKey + '].PurchasedQty'` supposed to work, when orders is not a child of customers?

Comment: @Zhorov : Is there any alternative way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: @Alex : Yes.. Orders are not child of Customers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to rebuild the whole JSON. In your case, because you only have one level of arrays to feed through `OPENJSON`, you can just rebuild that, and use `JSON_VALUE` and `JSON_MODIFY` to access the various values.

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have `JSON_AGG`. So to aggregate whole JSON objects you need `STRING_AGG` to aggregate, and also `JSON_QUERY` to prevent double-escaping

```sql
UPDATE t
SET JsonData =
  JSON_MODIFY(
    JsonData,
    '$.MultiOptions',
    JSON_QUERY((
        SELECT
          '[' + STRING_AGG(
            JSON_MODIFY(
              JSON_MODIFY(
                arr.value,
                '$.Orders.Dest1',
                JSON_VALUE(arr.value, '$.Customers.Source1')
              ),
              '$.Customers.PurchasedQty',
              JSON_VALUE(arr.value, '$.Customers.Qty')
            ),
            ','
          ) + ']'
        FROM OPENJSON(t.JsonData, '$.MultiOptions') arr
    ))
  )
FROM jsontable t;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ebbd7/9)

For older versions of SQL Server, it's even more complicated, as you need to use `FOR XML PATH('')` to aggregate, then manipulate it further to add `[]` and remove the leading comma.

```sql
UPDATE t
SET JsonData =
  JSON_MODIFY(
    JsonData,
    '$.MultiOptions',
    JSON_QUERY(
      STUFF(
        (
          SELECT
            ',' +
            JSON_MODIFY(
              JSON_MODIFY(
                arr.value,
                '$.Orders.Dest1',
                JSON_VALUE(arr.value, '$.Customers.Source1')
              ),
              '$.Customers.PurchasedQty',
              JSON_VALUE(arr.value, '$.Customers.Qty')
            )
          FROM OPENJSON(t.JsonData, '$.MultiOptions') arr
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
        1, 1, '['
      )
      + ']'
    )
  )
FROM jsontable t;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ebbd7/10)

Comment: I am using MS-2016 and getting 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: OK added you an option for that also.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use wild cards to modify all the items in the `$.MultiOptions` JSON array at once. In your case a possible solution is to parse the stored JSON content (using `OPENJSON()`) and rebuild the JSON again (using `FOR JSON PATH`):

```
UPDATE @jsontable
SET JsonData = JSON_MODIFY(
   JsonData,
   '$.MultiOptions',
   (
   SELECT 
      CustomerName AS [Customers.CustomerName],
      Address AS [Customers.Address], 
      Source1 AS [Customers.Source1], 
      OrderName AS [Orders.OrderName], 
      Qty AS [Orders.Qty], 
      Source1 AS [Orders.Dest1],      -- updated value
      Qty AS [Orders.PurchasedQty],   -- updated value
      IsMainOption AS [IsMainOption]
   FROM OPENJSON(JsonData, '$.MultiOptions') WITH (
      CustomerName nvarchar(max) '$.Customers.CustomerName', 
      Address nvarchar(max) '$.Customers.Address', 
      Source1 nvarchar(max) '$.Customers.Source1', 
      OrderName nvarchar(max) '$.Orders.OrderName', 
      Qty int '$.Orders.Qty', 
      IsMainOption bit '$.IsMainOption'
   )
   FOR JSON PATH  
   )
)
```